# How to merge other rows of data frame to the current row with Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame that looks something like this:

```
 A1    A2    A3    A4 
 1001  1002  1003  1004
 5001  5002  5003  5004
 7001  7002  7003  7004
```

I would like to merge the other rows to the current row to look like this. For Eg: For the first row the first four columns remain the same but the columns B1 to B4 are copy of 2nd row from A1 to A4 and C1 to C2 are copy of 3rd row from A1 to A4. Similar merging for the 2nd and 3rd row.

```
A1    A2    A3    A4     B1     B2    B3    B4     C1    C2    C3    C4
1001  1002  1003  1004   5001   5002  5003  5004   7001  7002  7003  7004
5001  5002  5003  5004   7001   7002  7003  7004   1001  1002  1003  1004
7001  7002  7003  7004   1001   1002  1003  1004   5001  5002  5003  5004
```

I have tried multiple things like groupby, indexing, icol, loops etc but unable to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already created the other two dataframes, you can just follow the concat code. Else you can create samples of the same dataframe based on `np.random.permutation` like below:

```
>>df1
    A1      A2      A3      A4
0   1001    1002    1003    1004
1   5001    5002    5003    5004
2   7001    7002    7003    7004

df2 = df1.iloc[np.random.permutation(len(df1))]
df2.columns=['B{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, len(df1.columns) + 1)]
>>df2
    B1      B2      B3      B4
1   5001    5002    5003    5004
0   1001    1002    1003    1004
2   7001    7002    7003    7004

df3 = df2.iloc[np.random.permutation(len(df2))]
df3.columns=['C{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, len(df1.columns) + 1)]
>>df3
    C1      C2      C3      C4
2   7001    7002    7003    7004
0   1001    1002    1003    1004
1   5001    5002    5003    5004
```

Once you have the dataframes ready, you can concat them on `axis=1` like:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],axis=1)

   A1    A2    A3    A4    B1    B2    B3    B4    C1    C2    C3    C4
0  1001  1002  1003  1004  5001  5002  5003  5004  7001  7002  7003  7004
1  5001  5002  5003  5004  7001  7002  7003  7004  1001  1002  1003  1004
2  7001  7002  7003  7004  1001  1002  1003  1004  5001  5002  5003  5004
```

**Note** This process is on permutations so you can expect equal number of combinations which would not be same everytime the code is ran.

Comment: Thanks, not having the same combinations would still work for my problem :)

Comment: @anky_91 - OP cannot upvote, because need minimal 15 points :)

Comment: @jezrael Didn't notice that. Sorry :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [np.roll](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) to perform a cyclic shift of the rows of df:

```
df2 = df.reindex(index=np.roll(df.index, -1)).reset_index(drop=True)
df2.columns = ['B{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, len(df.columns) + 1)]

df3 = df.reindex(index=np.roll(df.index, -2)).reset_index(drop=True)
df3.columns = ['C{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, len(df.columns) + 1)]

result = pd.concat([df, df2, df3], axis=1)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
     A1    A2    A3    A4    B1    B2    B3    B4    C1    C2    C3    C4
0  1001  1002  1003  1004  5001  5002  5003  5004  7001  7002  7003  7004
1  5001  5002  5003  5004  7001  7002  7003  7004  1001  1002  1003  1004
2  7001  7002  7003  7004  1001  1002  1003  1004  5001  5002  5003  5004
```

Comment: thanks. It helps, in the original data frame I have many more rows and columns, I  can your code in a loop to get the output :)

Answer (score 0):

This would be my approach of a general loop, which at least creates up to 25 reasonable further column names...:

```
n = 2   # number of rolled blocks to be concatenated
df2 = df
for i in range(n):
    df_roll = pd.DataFrame(np.roll(df, -(i+1), 0), columns=df.columns.str.replace('A', chr(66+i)))
    df2 = pd.concat([df2, df_roll], 1)
```

And again, thanks to @DanielMesejo for giving the hint to get in numpy what is not included in pandas: `roll`

Result for n=2:

```
     A1    A2    A3    A4    B1    B2    B3    B4    C1    C2    C3    C4                                                   
0  1001  1002  1003  1004  5001  5002  5003  5004  7001  7002  7003  7004                                               
1  5001  5002  5003  5004  7001  7002  7003  7004  1001  1002  1003  1004                                               
2  7001  7002  7003  7004  1001  1002  1003  1004  5001  5002  5003  5004
```